# cdk diff does not diff from console changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

1. I have a stack which creates IAM policies
   Its deployed successfully 
   I then change a policy by removing few statements
   Then invoke cdk diff, which does not detect the drift

Is this expected?

Comment: Yes that is expected CDK diff only works by comparing local stack with AWS stack so  does not detect changes in Infra on AWS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `cdk diff` will only compare the specified stack with the local template file (created by the previous `cdk deploy`).

Thus, if you made some changes in the AWS Console, the AWS CDK will not detect the drift.

Since version [1.17.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v1.17.0), you can now do the following to detect and show drifted changes:

```sh
cdk deploy --no-execute
```

From the [PR description:](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/4852)

> You will be able to see the ChangeSet in AWS CloudFormation Console, validate the resources and discard or execute the ChangeSet.